# Angular UI-Router - ng-init equivalent?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am starting to shift controller syntax in my router code, as in the following:

```
url: '/myRoute',
config: {
    templateUrl: 'app/my.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    title: 'avengers'
}
```

However one thing I can not find to replace is the ng-init function, often I require a function on init to be called that will either retrieve data or in other cases just required to run so it may perform some arbitrary functions.

I know there is a 'resolve' function but is there something more like an ng-init where I can say, run this controller function on load/transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO.

And also, please, check the doc to adjust the over-all usage of the `ngInit`:

#### [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

> The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.
>
> ***The only appropriate use** of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. **Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit`** to initialize values on a scope.*